# Is there an analogue of mathscinet for physics?

Tags: bibliography, physics

I've been looking recently at some papers in physics, from journals that are not listed in mathscinet.  Is there is a similar database for physics, with reviews and citation links?  I'd like to see where the papers I'm currently looking at have been referenced, in order to follow the subject forward in time.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but for high-energy physics there is spires: http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/

Comment: Google Scholar gives you a "cited by" link.

Comment: by the way... is there an analogue of MO for physics?

Comment: Bruno: physicsoverflow.com exists but is somewhat dormant.  It looks like the administrator hasn't visited in about 3 months.

Comment: @Bruno Martelli: There's http://physicsoverflow.com/ but I wouldn't say it's very active. There's also a proposal for Physics SE-2.0 http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=Ho2q28uHijgN5QfMOt5KEg2 which is currently in a pre-beta mode.

Comment: By the way, SPIRES is being superseded by INSPIRE, presently in beta: http://inspirebeta.net/

Answer (score 10):

In addition to freely available [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/advanced_scholar_search?hl=en&num=100) and [SPIRES](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/), and subscription-based [Web of Science](http://isiknowledge.com/WOS) and [Scopus](http://www.scopus.com/home.url), there is a free [NASA Astrophysics Data Systems database](http://www.adsabs.harvard.edu/) which, contrary to its title, appears to have broader scope than SPIRES, at least as far as mathematical physics is concerned; it provides abstracts (but not reviews), citations, and, for some older papers, their full-text scanned versions. Now it is sort of integrated with [arXiv.org](http://arxiv.org/): when looking at the abstract of any arXiv preprint, you see the link to its citations and references at NASA ADS under References & Citations. This database has, *inter alia*, a specialized [physics and geophysics search engine](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/physics_service.html).

Comment: I was going to chime in with xxx.lanl.gov  Which I haven't visited in over a decade.  I was surprised to find that it has since turned into arxiv.org, which I have been to more recently, but never bother to learn it's back story.  